# Notating simultaneous upbeat and grace notes in LilyPond

Tags: lilypond

I would like to transcribe Schumann's Kreisleriana, Op16-7 in LilyPond, but I don't know the source code to reproduce the red-circled part in the attached image. I would like to know the LilyPond source code for the part in question, or if anyone knows the structure of the notes. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Note: I am Japanese, and this text is translated from Japanese using DeepL because I am not familiar with English.

--Version and language of LilyPond--

version: 2.24.3

language: english

**Try.**

**1. If you consider that the 16th note of G and the 32nd triplet (grace note) overlap**

**1-1. When "<<>>" is used**

Source code:

```
\version "2.24.3"
\language "english"

global = {
    \time 2/4
    \tempo "Sehr rasch" 4 = 144
    \key c \minor
    \numericTimeSignature
}

right = \relative c'' {
    \global
    \clef treble
    << { \stemUp g16 } { \grace { \stemDown g32 c d } } >> 
}


left = \relative c {
    \global
    \clef bass
    r16
}

\score {
  \context PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff {
      \right
    }
    \new Staff {
      \left
    }
  >>
  \layout {
    \override Score.Clef.break-visibility = #all-invisible
    \override Score.KeySignature.break-visibility = #all-invisible
    \override Score.SystemStartBar.collapse-height = #1
  }
  \midi {}
}
```

Output:

[image]

**1-2. When described as is**

In the above source code, change only "right" as follows.

Source code (Corrected part only):

```
right = \relative c'' {
    \global
    \clef treble
    \stemUp g16 \grace { \stemDown g32 c d } 
}
```

Output:

[image]

In the above attempt, I thought that the 16th note of G and the 32nd triplet (grace note) overlapped, but it did not work. (I doubt if the main note and the ornamental note ever overlap in the first place...) Perhaps there is an error in both the musical interpretation and the source code description. I have no knowledge of music, and I am new to LilyPond, so this is what I get. I have been browsing the official documentation and websites about LilyPond and music, but have not been able to solve the problem. Please help me!

Comment: Those are "Grace notes".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blilypond%5D+grace+notes

Comment: They look like grace notes, but they are actual measured triplets.  See my answer below.

Comment: They are somehow neither. In the editions on [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Kreisleriana,_Op.16_(Schumann,_Robert)) too they are in smaller print, so I take them to be thought of as grace notes. But the first of them sharing note head with the upbeat makes them metered, which goes against my idea of grace notes. Robert Schumann, it’s a mess you’ve made. :-) Like you, rice, I would still want to typeset it as faithfully as we can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it:

```
\version "2.24.3"
\language "english"

global = {
    \time 2/4
    \tempo "Sehr rasch" 4 = 144
    \key c \minor
    \numericTimeSignature
}

right = \relative c'' {
    \global
    \clef treble
    \partial 16
    << 
      { g16 } 
      \\ 
      { \magnifyMusic #2/3 { \omit TupletNumber \tuplet 3/2 { g32 c d } } }
    >> 
    ef16( fs, c' ef)
}


left = \relative c {
    \global
    \clef bass
    \partial 16
    r16
    <g c a'>8->\arpeggio r
}

\score {
  \context PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff {
      \right
    }
    \new Staff {
      \left
    }
  >>
  \layout {
    \override Score.Clef.break-visibility = #all-invisible
    \override Score.KeySignature.break-visibility = #all-invisible
    \override Score.SystemStartBar.collapse-height = #1
  }
  \midi {}
}
```

What happening here is we notice that the grace notes are actually measured pickup notes (partial measure) and that they should be aligned with the 16th rest in the left hand.  These pickup notes are triplets but without the triplet number and smaller, so we magnify the music by 2/3 (that is, shrink it).  Also, the structure for simultaneous notes is `<< { } \\ { } >>`. Notice the two backslashes in the middle. (That's an oversimplification, see https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/multiple-voices)

It's a lot to take in for a beginner, but there it is.

Comment: Thank you! I got the expected outputs and also gained new knowledge about LilyPond. Although I am a beginner in both LilyPond and music theory, I will do my best.